# how to add images in executable jar?

Tags: executable-jar

I want to add images that JFrames use from image folder in executable jar. In eclipse executable jar is created but it does not include image folder. So how can i include that folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java & Eclipse: Resources in JAR?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883077/java-eclipse-resources-in-jar)